# Uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What's up guys?

I'm using the Twitter-Text gem in my RoR project, but I'm having troubles with the ApplicationHelper. I already see another topics with this same question on StackOverflow, but no one fix my problem.

Ok, let's take a look at my project:

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'twitter-text'
```

#### Application_Helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
    require 'twitter-text'
    include Twitter::Autolink
    include Twitter::Extractor
end
```

// I really don't know why I need create the following file:

#### helpers/twitter.rb

```
module TwitterText
end
```

#### helpers/twitter_helper.rb

```
module TwitterText      
end
```

#### controller/posts_controller.rb

```
require 'twitter-text'
include Twitter::Extractor
```

#### What I see in localhost error page:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::Twitter
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

#### What I see in my console:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::Twitter):
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:3:in `<module:ApplicationHelper>'
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

It's appear to be everything ok, what can I do to fix this trouble?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you restarted your web server after adding the gem and helpers?

Comment: Well, now works...thanks! Post as a answer and I'll give you the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

whenever installing new gems you have to restart your web server as your gems are loaded when the application environment starts. Those are installed to your global gem directory by doing a `bundle install.`